# GraphQL: Deep Filter on repeatable component throws error

Tags: vue.js, graphql, strapi

Describe the bug
I create a component "link" which consists of a language and a text field. This component is used in a content type and marked as repeatable.

In GraphQL I would like to filter on the language in order to get just one link entry. But the API throws the error "Your filters contain a field 'doc.link' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations"

Steps to reproduce the behavior

Create a component with two fields (e.g. test and link ) and a content type with some fields and this description component, mark it as repeatbale (see definitions below under Coder Snippets)
Create one entry with two link - one for EN.

Query:

```
query {
  test(where:{ doc: {link: "EN" } }) {
    Title
    Langu
    doc {
      link
      test1
    }
  }
}
```

Note: without the filter works.

Comment: can you show your model? it looks like your schema doesn't match what you are expecting